# Warhammer 40k item drop on boss fights

Tags: warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war-ii

I just finished warhammer 40k (Dawn of War 2), great game!

Sometimes when I finish boss battles, I can't pick up the item that drops from the boss because the game immediately goes into a cutscene (the screen height reduces and I lose mouse while a voiceover goes on). I'm just wondering whether I actually get those items at the end of the game. Since I never even get to hover over it, I don't know whether it's actually there in the loot that is shown at the end of the game.

This happened a couple of times including the final fight with the alpha hive tyrant. It dropped a blue item with a box shape, and I didn't even get to pick it up.

Comment: The blue item is the wargear that allows you to repair machines.

Comment: @Clockwork Haha thanks, this was over a decade. Gotta try the new warhammer game

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you don't. I believe this is a known bug. So whenever you finish a boss fight, try to frantically click on the drop. If you don't get them, don't worry, most of the time, old loots will not be useful soon.

UPDATE: After further looking up online and confirmed by 1) another player and 2) from a live stream by Husky playing DoWII Requisition: your wargears are automatically picked up at the end of the game.

Comment: ah dammit! I missed the very last drop. ah well

Comment: It's ok. You can always get Chaos Rising and the upcoming (any moment now) Retribution expansion. :-) Plenty more drops there that would make your previous wargear drops pale in comparison.

Comment: Note that nothing is carried over to Retribution - you start the Space Marines campaign at level 1, just like every other army.

Comment: @therefromhere Thanks for the information. My answer was post before the information about the single player campaign was available. Nevertheless, Retribution is a great game and I am sure the OP will enjoy it.

Comment: You don't even need to click on the wargears to pick them up. They're automatically added to your inventory. Clicking is just part of the fun.